# How to call mqtt client in background service flutter

Tags: flutter, service, background, mqtt

My project uses mqtt for notifications. And need real time notification.
I have mqtt class like this

```
class Mqtt {
...

  Mqtt._() {
    mqttClient = MqttServerClient.withPort(server, clientIdentifier, port);

    ///Successful connection callback
    mqttClient.onConnected = _onConnected;

    ///Disconnected callback
    mqttClient.onDisconnected = _onDisconnected;

    ///Subscription success callback
    mqttClient.onSubscribed = _onSubscribed;

    ///Subscription failure callback
    mqttClient.onSubscribeFail = _onSubscribeFail;
  }

  static Mqtt getInstance() {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = Mqtt._();
    }
    return _instance!;
  }

  ///connection
  connect() {
    mqttClient.connect();
    _log("connecting");
  }

...
}
```

And I call like this

```
Mqtt mqtt = Mqtt.getInstance();
mqtt.subTopic = 'NOTIFICATION/';
mqtt.connect();
```

But mqtt disconnects when app is stopped.
How to call mqtt client in background service flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [flutter foreground service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task) it might help you.